# Flatten data on Marshallow / SQLAlchemy Schema

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm having some issues with how I'm getting my data back from one of my endpoints - specifically, with Marshmallow and SQLAlchemy.

I have a many-to-many relationship between cocktails and ingredients, but I also have more data than just foreign keys on the relational table, ings_in_cocktail, such as `ounces.` When I GET `/cocktails/`, it returns something like this:

```
{
  "cocktails": [
    {
      "glass": "rocks",
      "ingredients": [
        {
          "ingredient": {
            "ing_type": "liquor",
            "id": 1,
            "name": "gin"
          },
          "ounces": 20
        }
      ],
      "finish": "stirred",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "gin and tonic"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'd like to do is combine the spread the `ounces` property with the `ingredient` dict.

I want the data to look like the following:

```
{
  "cocktails": [
    {
      "glass": "rocks",
      "ingredients": [
        {
          "ing_type": "liquor",
          "id": 1,
          "name": "gin",
          "ounces": 20
        }
      ],
      "finish": "stirred",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "gin and tonic"
    }
  ]
}
```

After searching the web for hours, I can't find a way to do this easily with Marshmallow. Is there some easy way I'm missing?

### Code

**ingredients.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from settings import db, ma

class Ingredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ingredients'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    ing_type = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

class IngredientSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
```

**ings_in_cocktail.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from settings import db, ma

from models.ingredients import Ingredient, IngredientSchema

class CocktailIngredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ings_in_cocktail'
    ing_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ingredients.id'), primary_key=True)
    cocktail_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cocktails.id'), primary_key=True)
    ounces = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    ingredient = db.relationship('Ingredient')

# Necessary for transforming sqlalchemy data into serialized JSON


class CocktailIngredientSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    ingredient = ma.Nested(IngredientSchema, strict=True)

    class Meta:
    model = CocktailIngredient
```

**cocktails.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from settings import db, ma

from models.ing_in_cocktails import CocktailIngredient, CocktailIngredientSchema
from models.ingredients import Ingredient, IngredientSchema

class Cocktail(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cocktails'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    glass = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    finish = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
    ingredients = db.relationship(
        'CocktailIngredient',
        # secondary='ings_in_cocktail',
        backref=db.backref('cocktails'),
        # primaryjoin=id == CocktailIngredient.cocktail_id
    )

# Necessary for transforming sqlalchemy data into serialized JSON
class CocktailSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    # this is responsible for returning all the ingredient data on the cocktail
    ingredients = ma.Nested(CocktailIngredientSchema, many=True, strict=True)
    class Meta:
    model = Cocktail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it like this:

```py
class CocktailSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    # this is responsible for returning all the ingredient data on the cocktail
    ingredients = ma.Nested(CocktailIngredientSchema, many=True, strict=True)
    ingredients = fields.Method('concat_ingredients_dicts')

    """
    at this point the ingredients field on the cocktail object looks something like this

    ingredients: [{
        ingredient: {
            name: 'white russian',
            glass: 'rocks',
            finish: 'stirred'
        },
        ounces: 2,
        action: 'muddle',
        step: 1
    }]

    what we want is to concat this data so "ingredients" just turns
    into an list of dicts
    """
    def concat_ingredients_dicts(self, obj):
        result_ingredients_list = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(list(obj.ingredients)):
            # create a dict from the fields that live in the relational table
            relational_fields_dict = {
                'ounces': obj.ingredients[i].ounces,
                'action': obj.ingredients[i].action,
                'step': obj.ingredients[i].step
            }

            # create a dict from the fields on each ingredient in the cocktail
            ingredients_dict = obj.ingredients[i].ingredient.__dict__
            ingredients_dict_extracted_values = {
                'name': ingredients_dict.get('name'),
                'type': ingredients_dict.get('ing_type'),
                'id': ingredients_dict.get('id')
            }

            # merge the two dicts together
            merged = dict()
            merged.update(ingredients_dict_extracted_values)
            merged.update(relational_fields_dict)

            # append this merged dict a result array
            result_ingredients_list.append(merged)
            i += 1
        # return the array of ingredients
        return result_ingredients_list

    class Meta:
      model = Cocktail
```

Answer (score 5):

*Update: I put a better solution at the bottom.*

You can achieve this by using `Method` or `Function` fields to allow a parent to get data from its child.  Here is what you need to do:

1. Leave `CocktailSchema` alone.
2. Get rid of `IngredientSchema` entirely (unless you also need it for something else).
3. Inside `CocktailIngredientSchema`, replace the `Nested` field with several `Function` fields that pull data right out of the inner "ingredient" object.

**Schemas Before**

```
class IngredientSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient


class CocktailIngredientSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    ingredient = ma.Nested(IngredientSchema)

    class Meta:
        model = CocktailIngredient


class CocktailSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    ingredients = ma.Nested(CocktailIngredientSchema, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cocktail
```

**Schemas After**

```
class CocktailIngredientSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    ing_type = ma.Function(lambda obj: obj.ingredient.ing_type)
    id = ma.Function(lambda obj: obj.ingredient.id)
    name = ma.Function(lambda obj: obj.ingredient.name)

    class Meta:
        model = CocktailIngredient


class CocktailSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    ingredients = ma.Nested(CocktailIngredientSchema, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cocktail
```

### A cleaner alternative for marshmallow version 3+ (requires Python 3)

1. Leave `CocktailSchema` alone.
2. Leave `IngredientSchema` alone (instead of getting rid of it as shown above).
3. Inside `CocktailIngredientSchema`, replace the `Nested` field with several `Pluck` fields that pull data right out of the inner schema.

**Schemas After**

```
class IngredientSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient


class CocktailIngredientSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    ing_type = ma.Pluck(IngredientSchema, 'ing_type')
    id = ma.Pluck(IngredientSchema, 'id')
    name = ma.Pluck(IngredientSchema, 'name')

    class Meta:
        model = CocktailIngredient


class CocktailSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    ingredients = ma.Nested(CocktailIngredientSchema, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cocktail
```

- [documentation for `fields.Function()` and `fields.Method()`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_fields.html#method-fields)
- [documentation for `fields.Pluck()`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Pluck)

Answer (score 1):

You can using a method field in `IngredientSchema`

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_fields.html#method-fields

Please check this to see how to use this field in documents.

Comment: The documentation does not help at all. I need a working example